# Entity framework core 2 SQL is always logged

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

After upgrading to asp.net + entity framework core 2 i noticed something weird.
Before (in 1.1), i had to use DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory to log SQL queries that were produced by ef, but now, i don't have to do it anymore, SQL queries are logged by default.

The logger factory is set to "Information"

```
loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/MyApp-{Hour}.txt", LogLevel.Information);
```

Shouldn't SQL queries be associated with Debug? is it normal? is there a way to keep the logging level Information and disabling just the SQL logging?

Comment: this seems odd to me. where do the sql queries get logged to by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that entity framework is supposed to log SQL in "Information"
I changed the loggerFactory to

```
loggerFactory.AddFile("Logs/MyApp-{Hour}.txt", LogLevel.Information, new Dictionary<string, LogLevel>()
            {
                { "Microsoft", LogLevel.Error },
                { "System", LogLevel.Error }
            });
```

So that everything with "Microsoft" or "System" in it's namespace would log only Errors (or anything above)